# Using $text search inside $or in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, text-search

I'm trying to use $text search inside $or.

```
await Creators.aggregate([
 {$match: {
  $or: [
    { $creatorId: { $in: [407, 409] } }, 
    { $text: { $search: "Michael"} } ] 
  } }
])
```

The query won't work. But the $text without $or works fine.

Does anyone have an idea about this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: $or a full-text search and an $in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116182/mongodb-or-a-full-text-search-and-an-in)

Answer (score 1):

The [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text) operator expression cannot used in $or or $not expressions when used in aggregation. Refer [to doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html#behavior)